# Making preview in writing page using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsp, preview

I want have a preview in my writing page just like here in StackOverFlow question writing.

Everytime i press enterkey in the textarea, it doesn't make new line but just a space.

Instead of typing >br< tag in the textarea, I want pressing enterkey as really making a new line in the preview area.

Please help me and Thank you.

here's my code

```html
<html>
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<head>
<script>
 var app = angular.module("myApp", [ 'ngSanitize' ]);

 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <textarea ng-model="myText"></textarea>
  <p id="contentsPreview" ng-bind-html="myText"></p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are ok with HTML take a look at [TextAngular here](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular). Pretty awesome directive where newlines are formatted and you could just switch out your `<textarea>` tag with textAngular and be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with css

```
#contentsPreview {
  white-space: pre;// or pre-line
}
```

Otherwise use a function or filter to replace `\n` with `<br>`

```
$scope.n2br = function(str){
   return str.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>')
}
```

Comment: many many tnx. First one works but I dont know how to make second one work. Do I only put that statement into the app.controller or need to add something else? another tnx in advance.

Comment: No would need to call it in view ...something like: `ng-bind-html="n2br(myText)"`